# How to run IOS browser tests on SauceLabs from Intern 3

Tags: intern, saucelabs

Has anyone gotten Intern 3 to run iOS tests on SauceLabs?

I've tried many configurations for the environment, including what's written on [how to run Intern's self-tests on mobile on SauceLabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019561/how-to-run-interns-self-tests-on-mobile-on-saucelabs) and what's suggested by https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator, but I can't even get it to start without giving some error like about  Repeated sequence for session ...: 238 last 0 cur.

Comment: Specifically what version of Intern 3 are you using? 3.0.3?

Comment: Also, I just got `{ browserName: 'iphone', platform: 'OS X 10.10', version: '9.0', deviceName: 'iPad Retina' }` with SauceLabs without errors for one of my projects.

Comment: I am using Intern 3.0.3.  Starting to look like an intermittent error or something random like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I'm able to follow Kitson's advice and use

```
{ browserName: 'iphone', platform: 'OS X 10.10',
  version: '9.0', deviceName: 'iPad Retina' }
```

It just fails intermittently.